# How to display elements of this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, output

```
var arr = [2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9]
var newArr = (arr.sort())

for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
  if (newArr[i] == newArr[i + 1]) {
    var rem = [console.log(i)] //- (a)

  }
console.log(rem[0])
```

I want all the values of `i` for which the number is repeating in `newArr` array. Statement (a) gives me the indices and I want to store them in an array named `rem`. However `console.log(rem[0])` is undefined. What can I do?

Comment: `var rem = [console.log(i)] //- (a)` will *overwrite* `rem` every iteration of the loop. Moreover `console.log(i)` will always return `undefined` - it *logs* what you give it, but the value *produced* by the call is `undefined`, so `[console.log(i)]` is always `[undefined]` - an array with one element in it and that element is `undefined`.

Comment: What's `var rem = [console.log(i)]`? probably should be `rem = [i]`. Note that `rem` variable has to be declared outside of the loop.

Comment: @VLAZ How can I store the repeating values then?

Comment: @Cid  if it was a `let` or `const` it would, but it's a `var`, so it won't go out of scope until the function end.

Comment: Ah true, it's a `var`, I'm always confused about their scoping, I never use them

Comment: @Anon declare `rem` outside and assign it to an array. Then in the loop *add* items to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean this?

```js
var arr = [2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9]
var newArr = (arr.sort())
var rem = []; // create your rem array outside
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
  if (newArr[i] == newArr[i + 1]) {
    rem.push(i); // if "i" matches your criteria, add it to the array.
  }
}
console.log(rem); // rem has the full list of indices
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var arr = [2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9]
var newArr = (arr.sort())
vare rem = []

for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
  if (newArr[i] == newArr[i + 1]) {
    rem.push(newArr[i]);

  }
console.log(rem[0])
```